# TCP [RST,ACK] ignored

Tags: windows, tcp, rst

I have a Windows 2008 server and an application that connects over Internet to it. 
From time to time I see that I receive a TCP [RST, ACK] that is ignored by my application. 
Using TCPViewer I still can see that connection still up.
I did different Wireshark captures and I can see that in case of the RST ignore, another packet is send back, and the connection is never dropped.

```
269037 72.5.42.235  172.16.1.138 TCP 60 9003→54020 [RST, ACK]
    Seq=2655287284 Ack=371936778 Win=0 Len=0
269038 172.16.1.138 72.5.42.235  TCP 66 [TCP Dup ACK 268965#33] 54020→9003 [ACK]
    Seq=371936778 Ack=2655238984 Win=2097120 Len=0 SLE=2655243124 SRE=2655287284
```

This usually happens when the connection is bad and I get a lot of latency, delayed packets and retransmission.
Can somebody explain the situation when RST may be ignored by an application or operating system?

Comment: "I have a Windows 2008 server and an application that connects over Internet to it."  Oh here we go...   What is your problem?  What leads you to believe that a sysadmin can fix it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not know that this is a sysadmin group. I just wanted to know the situations when a [RST, ACK] packet may be ignored, and it does not result in closing a TCP connection.

Comment: That's because you didn't read the Help tour or FAQ.  You might want to try your question at http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/